# IIS Application Pool Redirect

Tags: iis, web-applications

I have been doing some research and some thought into this for awhile, and can't seem to find a quality solution.

When we update our web software, we have to kill the application pool associated with the site. Not a big deal right?

Except customers are complaining they don't know why they see a 503 error and submit unnecessary tickets.

Things I know:

- There is no way to customize the 503 page
- This is normal when the application pool is down
- We can't leave the application pool on while updating

Is it possible to have the site redirect to another site or different application pool on failure?

If it is I can create a "maintenance" page site and just have it redirect on error.

Answer (score 0):

Until I know you can configure error pages from IIS Manager. Under the section .NET Error Pages.

By the way I think your solution should be posible using [URL Rewriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

[Here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1155291.aspx) @ruslany shows an example about how to do any request of a site returns a 503.

and [here](https://blogs.iis.net/bills/Improving-Custom-Errors-for-IIS7-Server) you can read about error pages customization using that module

also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis) a very good documentation about.

And to provide a bit of code. You are supposed to replace error pages like this:

```
<httpErrors>

<error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="401.htm" />
<error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="403.htm" />
<error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="404.htm" />
<error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="405.htm" />
<error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="406.htm" />
<error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="412.htm" />
<error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="500.htm" />
<error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="501.htm" />
<error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="c:\inetpub\custerr" path="502.htm" />

</httpErrors>
```